# How to determine the number in aws_instance.main.*.public_ip in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to add different messages to the output results of the server I made first and the server I made the second and later, and display it.

What I want to do is as follows finally.

```
output
  ec2global_ips  [
    manager_ip is : xxx,
    node ip is: [xxx,xxx]
]
```

currently my output.tf code is as follows.

```
output "ec2_global_ips" {
  value = ["${aws_instance.main.*.public_ip}"]
}
```

For that, I think that it is necessary to judge somewhere `aws_instance.main.0.public_ip` or `aws_instance.main.1.public_ip` and put another value

Is there a way to make such a thing with terraform?
The var.count function could not be used in output.tf etc.

Comment: Why not just split them across 2 different outputs so you have `ec2_manager_ips` and `ec2_node_ips`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the slice and element interpolations (code untested):

```
output "ec2_global_ips" {
  value = "${
    map(
      "manager_ip", "${element(aws_instance.main.*.public_ip, 0)}"
      "node_ips", "${slice(aws_instance.main.*.public_ip, 1, length(aws_instance.main.*.public_ip))}"
    )
  }"
}
```

Judging by your desired output it looks like you're looking for manager_ip to be a string (hence the element and not a slice for it) and node_ips to be a list. This should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: No problem. I actually don't remember many of the interpolation commands, I just check the docs (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html) whenever I'm wondering if Terraform can do something.